# Hide and show is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with JQ script and I cannot find the bug. When I select the Yes option from the selection box the website should display "Type your email address" and hide the "Type your new username". 
Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>  

<script>
$(function () {
$('#am').on('change', function () {

    var stringt = $('#am :selected').val();

    if (stringt === "Yes") {
        $("#campos1").hide();
        $("#campos2").show();
    } else {
        $("#campos1").show();
        $("#campos2").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script> 
</head>
<html>
   <li>Are you already a member?
    <select name="am">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
      <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
   </li>
 <div id="campos1">
   <li>Type you email address.
    <input id="Field5" name="institucion_1" type="text" />
   </li>
 </div>
 <div id="campos2">
   <li>Type a new username.
    <input type="text" />
   </li>
 </div>
 </html>
```

Here's the jSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/CcCbQ/5/
Feel free to modify and suggest me any comments. :)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't match the code you posted in this question.

Comment: I think you posted the wrong fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to select the element by its id but it has none just a name give it an id then you can select it by its id, also the values of the select is 1 and 2 not Yes and No

```
<select name="am" id="am">

...
if (stringt === "1") {
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multiple errors

corrected code below

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>  

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#am').change( function () {

    var stringt = $('#am :selected').val();

    if (stringt === "1") {
        $("#campos1").hide();
        $("#campos2").show();
    } else {
        $("#campos1").show();
        $("#campos2").hide();
    }
  });
});
</script> 
</head>
<html>
   <li>Are you already a member?
    <select name="am" id="am">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
      <option value="2">No</option>
    </select>
   </li>
 <div id="campos1">
   <li>Type you email address.
    <input id="Field5" name="institucion_1" type="text" />
   </li>
 </div>
 <div id="campos2">
   <li>Type a new username.
    <input type="text" />
   </li>
 </div>
 </html>
```